# Backendless issue, how to prevent push notification from showing

Tags: java, android, push-notification, backendless

Without the use of unregister to push notifications, i want, in certain conditions, to prevent the notification from being shown in android notification center.

there is a chunk of code from the backendless that do the following:

```
public class MyPushService extends BackendlessPushService
{

    @Override
    public boolean onMessage( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
        if (...) do something that shows the notif
        else do something to hide the notif (not showing the notif at all)
    }

    @Override
    public void onError( Context context, String message )
    {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

From the documentation in: https://backendless.com/documentation/messaging/android/messaging_push_notification_setup_androi.html

> The implementation of the
>   method in the BackendlessPushService class contains the logic of
>   displaying push notifications in the Android Notification Center. To
>   cancel the default handling of the push notification, make sure your
>   code returns false.

even when i return false, i still see the notification, how do i prevent that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the documentation on GitHub: https://github.com/Backendless/Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/push.md

In order to accomplish not displaying push notification, you need to do the following:

1. Override `BackendlessPushService` and return `false` from `onMessage()` method
2. Override `BackendlessBroadcastReceiver` and return your implementation class from `getServiceClass()` method
3. Declare your overriding receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`

All these steps are described in details with code by the link provided above.